# Add margin to icon when the parent element on :hover using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, hover, icons, css-transitions

I have an icon with some text. When anywhere on the `<a>` element is hovered on I want to `margin-left: 40px;` the svg. How can I do this only using HTML CSS.
Essentially anywhere the a tag is hovered - adding a style to a child element.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="text-link">
    <span class="text">Text Link</span><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="img/icons/icon.svg#arrow" /></svg>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.text-link {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.icon {
    margin-left: 20px;
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}
.icon:hover {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

This adds a margin when the icon is hovered on but I'm wanting to add the margin when anywhere on the  tag is hovered on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share your current working sample or css. I can't understand what you need..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
.parent:hover .child {
 /* CSS here */
}
```

In your case :-

```
a:hover svg{
  margin-left:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Main roles is using css style that

```
.parent-tag:hover .child-tag{
   /* Your CSS */
}
```

But in your case the solution is

```
a:hover svg{
   margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Write hover code on `.text-link:hover`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.text-link {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 20px;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

.text-link:hover .icon {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.text {
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="text-link">
  <span class="text">Text Link</span>
  <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px">
<path fill-rule="evenodd"  fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)"
 d="M11.998,24.000 C5.383,24.000 0.001,18.617 0.001,12.001 C0.001,5.384 5.383,0.000 11.998,0.000 C18.615,0.000 23.999,5.384 23.999,12.001 C23.999,18.617 18.615,24.000 11.998,24.000 ZM11.998,1.101 C5.990,1.101 1.102,5.991 1.102,12.001 C1.102,18.010 5.990,22.899 11.998,22.899 C18.008,22.899 22.898,18.010 22.898,12.001 C22.898,5.991 18.008,1.101 11.998,1.101 ZM7.146,19.854 L11.843,11.957 L7.146,4.306 L20.611,12.079 L7.146,19.854 Z"/>
</svg>
</a>
```